# Matplotlib how to overlay probability density function onto baseline plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to overlay a probability distribution on a baseline graph. An MRE is below, and then the desired outcome is shown below by just copying/rotating/squeezing the plots in PowerPoint as an example.

```
# Import python libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats

# Plot example PDF
x1 = np.logspace(start=np.log(0.1), stop=np.log(3), num=200, base=np.e)
ln_mu, ln_sigma = 1.1, 0.3
y1 = np.exp(stats.norm.pdf(x1, ln_mu, ln_sigma))
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.fill_between(x1, min(y1), y1, alpha=0.5)
ax.set(xscale="log", xlim=[min(x1), max(x1)])
plt.show()
```

[image]

```
# Plot example baseline curve
x2 = np.arange(0, 1.05, 0.05)
y2 = 2*np.sqrt(np.pi*x2)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x2,y2)
ax.set(yscale="log", ylim=[min(x1), max(x1)])
plt.show()
```

[image]

**Here is what I am trying to produce using matplotlib.** (The axes on the pdf should be turned off, I just didn't crop them out for the purposes of illustrating this example.) Let's assume that the right (straight) edge of the PDF should be at x=0.1125.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You want `twiny` and to plot your distribution with `fill_betweenx`:

```
# Import python libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats

# Plot example PDF
x1 = np.logspace(start=np.log(0.1), stop=np.log(3), num=200, base=np.e)
ln_mu, ln_sigma = 1.1, 0.3
y1 = np.exp(stats.norm.pdf(x1, ln_mu, ln_sigma))
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

x2 = np.arange(0, 1.05, 0.05)
y2 = 2*np.sqrt(np.pi*x2)
ax.plot(x2,y2)
ax.set(yscale="log", ylim=[min(x1), max(x1)])

ax2 = ax.twiny()
ax2.fill_betweenx(x1, min(y1), y1, alpha=0.5)
ax2.set(yscale="log", ylim=[min(x1), max(x1)])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: that's different than the desired output in the OP in a few ways: The pdf spans the whole plot, left to right; it's facing the wrong way; it's not at x = 0.11, it's at x=0; and there is a top x-axis for the pdf that should be omitted

Comment: Umm, OK, you don't think you can figure it out from there?  If you don't like twiny, you can use `inset_axes` to place the axes in data space.

Comment: well, for example, how do you place the twin at x=0.11, not x =0?